# Why use random variables instead of probability spaces

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question, random-variables, convention

When talking about various ways to model something probabilistically, many authors prefer to use random variables, instead of probability distributions.  Of course, **this difference is more of a point of view, than of actual mathematical substance** - yet I'm very much interested in **why** the random variables point-of-view is assumed? Let me elaborate below on this.

It seems to me that this comes from not being fully explicit and formal, when building your model - since if you would be, that you would see that using random variables is actually very artificial and using the probability distribution is actually much more natural.
Consider the following problem:
*Suppose we have a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^{p}$ that we interpret as
the visible attributes of individual. For example, $x$ might represent
a loan applicants age, gender, race, and credit history.
We consider the problem of modeling whether we should give a person
represented by $x$ a loan; let $y\in\{0,1\}$ represent the target
of this prediction, i.e. whether an individual will have defaulted
on a loan he received ($y=0$) or repaid it according to his contract
($y=1$).*
To formalize this problem, we can  define random variables $X$ and $Y$
that take on values $X=x$ and $Y=y$ for an individual drawn randomly
from the population of interest (e.g., the population of ).
We define the *true risk*
\begin{equation}
r(x)=Pr(Y=1|X=x)\ \ (1).
\end{equation}
Then the problem is how to estimate this risk from data, yadda, yadda.

The issue I mention above is related to the formulation (not the solution
or theoretical framework) of this problem. Usually the above description
is all that you get!

Let us investigate how we can make it even more precise:
If we begin to be more explicit, in order to even introduce random
variables $X,Y$ we need a sample space. Because these random variables
appear in the expression (1), which explicitly is
$$
r(x)=Pr(\{\omega\in\Omega:Y(\omega)=1\}|\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)=x\}),
$$
the random variables furthermore need to be defined on the same sample
space. We could pick $\Omega:=\mathbb{R}^{p}\times\{0,1\}$ as a suitable
candidate, where a distribution $\mathcal{D}$ on it models how likely
it is that a certain individual is drawn from it. We could then define
$X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{p}$ as the projection onto the first
$p$ components and $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ as the projection
onto the last component. By doing so, we have given (1) a concrete
meaning.

But defining the random variables like this is rather cumbersome;
since we already needed to introduce $\Omega$ and $\mathcal{D}$
to even talk about random variables, we could just use these two ingredients
to define the true risk by
\begin{equation}
r(x)=Pr(\{\omega\in\Omega:\omega_{p+1}=1\}|\{\omega\in\Omega:\omega_{1,\ldots,p}=x\}) \ \ (2),
\end{equation}

where subscripts indicate the $p$-th coordinate.

But somehow a formulation as in (2) is very rarely used. My question
is: Why does the community tend to prefer a vague way of defining
random variables, that, if made precise, is actually more tedious
to set up(as I have just shown) than using the formulation (2) ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112476/discussion-on-question-by-temo-why-use-random-variables-instead-of-probability-s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the probability space might seem more natural, but random variables are more elegant because usually we do not care about the probability space. Yes, in real applications, the probability space is relatively straightforward to point out, but it's not actually important. There is some quantity we care about, or multiple quantities we care about, and they are somehow dependent on each other or they aren't. And it's these quantities and their interplay we really care about, so why not do the theoretical groundwork with a focus on those quantities - random variables.

Another reason is that random variables give us an elegant method to describe events. Any event can be described as the preimage of a usually simple set under a random variable, and then knowledge about the random variable translates to knowledge about the event. Especially (in)dependence of events can be elegantly treated with (in)dependent random variables.

Comment: Can you please give a concrete instance that illustrates your statement *"Yes, in real applications, the probability space is relatively straightforward to point out, but it's not actually important. There is some quantity we care about, or multiple quantities we care about, and they are somehow dependent on each other or they aren't. And it's these quantities and their interplay we really care about, so why not do the theoretical groundwork with a focus on those quantities - random variables."* as well as your second paragraph? In this general formulation I have trouble accepting them.

Comment: A survey could try to find out about the political leanings of certain religions by asking random people about their religious and political affiliation. The underlying probability space is the set of all inhabitants of a country with its power set as a $\sigma$-algebra and an ideally uniform distribution. But we don't care about wether the survey asked Barbara Smith. We only care that she was a pastafarian anarchist, so there's no point in modeling the entire probability space in detail. As for the second point, what do you want to know specifically?

Comment: Aha! This will be interesting if I formalize it: Let's assume the
country has 10 million inhabitants; let $\Omega:=\{1,\ldots,10^{7}\}$.
Then $(\Omega,\mathcal{P}(\Omega),\mu_{\text{uniform}})$ is the probability
space that you mentioned. Ok, but we don't care about the sample $64223\in\Omega$,
which represents Barbara Smith, we only care if she was pastafarian
anarchist (my favourite type of people). That means, we have a random
variable $K:\Omega\rightarrow R\times P$, where $R$ the finite set
of possible religious orientations and  [...]

Comment: [...] and $P$ is the finite set of possible
political orientations and we only care if $K(64223)=(\text{pastafarian},\text{anarchist})$.
But this means, the information of whether Barbara Smith is a pastafarian
anarchist is not even contained in the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{P}(\Omega),\mu_{\text{uniform}})$,
it is only contained in the random variable $K$. In other words,
you can build your probability space before you survey your whole
country (where you might ask many more questions, other than regarding
political and religious inclination) but [...]

Comment: [...] you can build your random variable only
afterwards, since it encodes the outcome of the survey. But hold on! This is contradictory to what you wrote. You wanted to
have the probability space contain **all** the information and the
random variable to merely isolate the quantity we care about out of
all that information. Ok, we can that too: [...]

Comment: The fact that it's the longest sequence of comments you every wrote is a hint that this is unnecessarily complicated. But the real problem is that it is highly inflexible. You went to great lengths to custom build a probability space which describes both of our random variables. But what if we suddenly decided that we want to survey a third fact, like preferred diet? We'd have to build a new probability space all over again. With random variables, we'd just have to define a new random variable on the same old probability space

Comment: I would not say I went to great length. I merely made it two possibilities explicit of what one would need to keep in ones mind when treating this example.

Comment: But please do answer. I would be really interested in sorting out these confusions that I have once and for all.

Comment: The point is that we don't have to manually encode any information in the probability space. We can just say that there *is* a probability space containing all the information we might ever need, and we extract the information using random variables. How the probability space looks is secondary. In fact, how the random variables look is also secondary. The only things that matter are their (joint) distributions, because those contain all the interesting information. This is why you will rarely find an author saying "Let $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ be an RV". It's just "Let $X$ be a real RV".